# Deployed sharepoint-hosted app not accessible

Tags: deployment, publishing-site, sharepoint-hosted-app

I have created a sharepoint-hosted app (sharepoint 2013) and I cannot publish it.

I already deployed another provider-hosted apps, the CNAME is configured an seems to work... but when I try to publish a sharepoint-hosted app it is not accessible.

Creating the .app and upload it into the app catalog doesn't report errors, but when trying to run it, it says the page cannot be displayed.

What is strange is that if I run the deploy option from visual studio, the app appears in the "apps in testing" section and I can access to the app BUT only from the same machine that deployed it.

When running a ping to the app from different machines it cannot be resolved.

```
ping apps-e5a793e589a590.w62sp15-appstest.oms-dev.local

Ping request could not find host apps-e5a793e589a590.w62sp15-appstest.oms-dev.local. Please check the name and try again.
```

Any idea about it?